# get the psk from wpa_passphrase with perl

Tags: regex, perl

i want to return the cryptet passphrase from wpa_passphrase into a perl script.
when i put:

```
wpa_passphrase mywifi mypassword
```

i got this result:

```
network={
    ssid="mywifi"
    #psk="mypassword"
    psk=f7170c7cf32060e75d4a0a9dad35640ee513c4d3706f55b4358f31c4b768ed21
}
```

in perl i was try with 5 lines

```
my $res = `/usr/bin/wpa_passphrase  mywifi  mypassword`; 
my $res2 = substr($V_FILERESULT,index($res ,"psk")+4);
$res2  = substr($res2 ,index($res2 ,"psk")+4,length($res2 )-2);
$res2  = substr($res2 ,0,length($res2 )-2); 
$res2  =~ s/\s+$//g;
```

it works, but i think is not very clean code. do you have a idea how i can write in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
`/usr/bin/wpa_passphrase  mywifi  mypassword` =~ /\spsk=(.*)/;
print $1;
```

pattern details:

```
\s       # a white character
psk=     # psk=
(.*)     # capturing group 1: all the content until the newline
```